# Can't uninstall GlassFish 3

Tags: glassfish, uninstallation

Okay, so here is the deal:

I was trying to install the java jdk so i can work on an android project in eclipse on this computer, but there are just so many different installations of java its impossible, for me atleast, to figure out exactly which one i needed. so i went with "JDK 7u3 with Java EE". But this also installed this GlassFish stuff, which i have no idea what is or what it does, and when i was going through all the eclipse stuff i decided to just keep my other computer for work. so i removed eclipsed and the stuff needed for that, and i removed the java stuff, but then when i try to uninstall the GlassFish, it can't, and gives me the error:

"Could not find the required version of the Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment in '(null)'."

I have now been trying for several hours, scouring the web to figure out some way of removing this, install all kinds of java stuff, removing it again, reinstalling, but nothing works. I don't really care what GlassFish is or what it does, i just want it, and all the java stuff gone for good.

How can i accomplish this?

Answer (score 5):

under Microsoft Windows 7 (or others), use that command line :

uninstall.exe -j "%JAVA_HOME%"

Answer (score 2):

You installed first jdk1.6 then uninstalled it. In this time, you install glassfish3 and glassfish wrote `set AS_JAVA=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_x` in its config file but you use now jdk1.7

1. Open C:\glassfishv3\glassfish\config\asenv.bat
2. Search 'set AS_JAVA'
3. Change its value to your current jdk path ( eg. C:\Progra¨1\Java\jdk1.7.xx )
4. Try to uninstall again.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the uninstall specifying the jvm to use:

try this following **command** to uninstall

```
C:\glassfish3\uninstall.exe -j <java home dir>
```

as stated in the error message. it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

GlassFish is a Java EE application server developed in open source, so you can create server-side services that your android apps can consume.  Of course, is sounds like you are not really interested in this :-)

The Java EE SDK install/uninstall instructions are here: http://java.sun.com/javaee/sdk/javaee6sdk_install.jsp

What you probably want to download, the Java 7 SDK (JDK 7) is here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Make sure you download the JDK (Java Developer Kit) and not the JRE (Java Runtime Environment).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

These didn't work for me running java 1.6.0_24 in Windows 7:

- I tried modifying the asenv.bat file that glassfish uses to find the jre to point to my jre.
- I tried manually putting it in as in C:\glassfish3\uninstall.exe -j .  This was per the official Oracle documentation.

The only thing that worked was to use the original path and move the bin and lib folders from my java installation to the directory that the error dialog 
specified.  Then the Glassfish uninstall started up and completed with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to uninstall the glasshfish server by using the below command

uninstall.exe -javahome "%JAVA_HOME%"

Note: We need to set the JAVA_HOME in the environment variable and classpath variable